# Question About A Problem Involving Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm currently stuck on this inequality problem:
[image]
[image]

So far,  I tried to prove it by using a proof by contrapositive, but that doesn't seem to work. Could I get a hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really just a hint, however you can stop reading after the line below and consider completing yourself.
$$\frac{bc-ad}{bd} = \frac{c}d-\frac{a}b = \left(\frac{c}d-\frac{p}q \right) + \left(\frac{p}q-\frac{a}b \right)\geqslant \frac1{dq}+\frac1{bq}$$
as each term in the brackets is positive.

> $$\implies q \geqslant \frac{b+d}{bc-ad} $$

> Similarly, considering $\displaystyle \frac{d}c<\frac{q}p<\frac{b}a$ also holds, we must have $p \geqslant \dfrac{a+c}{bc-ad}$

BTW, the "lowest" such fraction is called the *mediant* $= \dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$.

Comment: You can use a double-character prefix `>!` to a line to hide its contents. The trick is widely used at [Puzzling StackExchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) to prevent readers from inadvertently  reading solutions to puzzles. :)

Comment: Thanks @CiaPan, will do this time as you have reminded.  I remember doing this sometime ago - however seems difficult to remember personally though, just for the few occasions someone wants incomplete answers.

Comment: @Macavity Thank you so much, I understand how to solve it now.